# Getting users location by curl

Tags: php, curl, geolocation

Im having dificult having users location by Curl.

i have this code :

```
$ip ='123.125.114.144';
$result ='Unkown' ;
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5; // set to zero for no timeout
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.iptolatlng.com/?ip='.$ip);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$ip_data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if($ip_data && $ip_data->countryFullName != null)  //---the error is in this line
{
    $result = $ip_data->countryFullName;
}

echo $result;
```

However im getting this error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /mywebsite/index.php on line 29
>   Unknown

for testing purpose this is their link with random ip http://www.iptolatlng.com/?ip=123.125.114.144

any help will be much apreciated on whats going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl_exec` returns the result of the request in type of **string**, while you are trying access the result value in type of **object**.
Because your request returns json string, you should use the function `json_decode`.

Example:

```
$ip_data = curl_exec($ch);
$ip_obj = json_decode($ip_data);
echo $ip_obj->countryFullName;
```

Comment: Perfect ! thats what i was missing :) , thanks worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please select it as the right answer if it helped you :)